# How can I run python script as linux command

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python script: `/usr/bin/doxypy.py`

I have added `#!/usr/local/bin/python` as first line and given full permission to script with `chmod 777 /usr/bin/doxypy.py`.

If I want to run it as a linux command, let's say, I want to run it with only `doxypy`, is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, rename it to `/usr/bin/doxypy`

Comment: Thanks much! It worked!

Answer (score 1):

Rename the file to `doxpy` and put it in a folder of `$PATH`, e.g. `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 1):

remove the **.py** in the name and add this in the first line of the file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

then give the run permission with

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/doxypy
```

Its not a good practice, give all permissions to a file because any user can edit it, so just add the execution access right

Comment: Thanks for the correction! Appreciate your answer.